# jquery element sortable

Tags: jquery, element, jquery-ui-sortable

How can i find out which element is selected for sorting

Comment: I would like to help but you do not answer or mark any of the answers to your other questions therefore my help to you is at an end.

Comment: If your are going to participate here read the FAQ. Anybody else who finds your questions from google will not know what solution fixed your problem if you do not comment & mark an answer.

Comment: Sorry from now onwards i will do so.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#your-element').sortable({ //this is initial config for sortable element
  axis: 'y',
  cursor: 'crosshair',
  delay: 100,
  opacity: 0.6,
  scroll: true,
  update: function(event, ui) { //Element ready to be dropped to new place
    source_element = $(ui.item); // here is your selected item
  }
});
```